# save Smarty values dynamically in Multidimensional JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I fetched data from the db and saved it in a smarty array. Now I want to save those values in a javascript array and i dont know the size of it.

```
{foreach from=$car_owner item=car_item}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">
                <script>
                    var arrayPos = [
                        ['{$car_item['longitude']}', '{$car_item['latitude']}']]
                    ];
                </script>
                {$car_item['carName']}
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

The array is only saving one value for the longitude and one for the latitude despite that i have more than one value for each one. Im sure i need to loop it, but as i said i dont know the size of what i should loop because the `$car_owner` array contains data fetched from the db.
An help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: - Look to this package, it might help you: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: @MuhammadSadiq Sorry, it didnt help. My problem is when i use the array outside the script tag i only get the last value because it is all inside a loop, and i dont get the older values..

Comment: okay, then put foreach inside of the array

Comment: define js array outside of the loop and then inside of loop, push the values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two loops.

```
<script>
var arrayPos = [
{foreach from=$car_owner item=car_item}
    ['{$car_item['longitude']}', '{$car_item['latitude']}']]{if !$car_item@last},{/if}
{/foreach}
];
</script>

{foreach from=$car_owner item=car_item}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">{$car_item['carName']}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```